# Finding sequential recurrences in a list of numbers

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x, sorting

I have a list like this:

```
seq = [-2,3,-2,3,5,3,7,1,4,-5,1,4,-5,1,4,-5]
```

I want to get all the sequential recurrences and where it happens, I feel the way I'm doing its too brute force and in reality I want this for several lists each with length of about 300.

```
dic = {}
for p1 in range(len(seq)):
    for p2 in range(p1+1,len(seq)):
        dic.setdefault(tuple(seq[p1:p2]), []).append((p1,p2))
```

which results in all unique sequences of numbers as keys and their positions as values, for example:

```
#-2,3: [(0,2),(2,4)]
```

But also results in a lot of entries that occur only once that don't interest me, I'm 'cleaning' these after by taking only values that have more than 1 entry:

```
def clean(dic):
    cleandic = {}
    for key, value in dic.items():
        if len(value) > 1:
            cleandic.setdefault(key,value)
    return cleandic

cleandic = clean(dic)
```

Now for the last step I'm trying to get rid of the occurrences that happens inside the bigger ones, so I sorted the dict by reverse len of keys (bigger keys comes first), for example:

```
#(1,4,-5,1,4,-5) : ([7,13),(10,16)]
#...
#(1,4,-5) : [(7,10),(10,13)]
```

The best I came up with to take out the small ones:

```
sorteddic = dict(sorted(cleandic.items(), key=lambda item: len(item[0]), reverse=True))

onlybigs = {}
while len(sorteddic) > 0:
    for key1, values1 in sorteddic.items():
        for key2, values2 in sorteddic.copy().items():
            if len(key2) == len(key1):
                continue
            for value1 in values1:     #ex: (7,13)
                for value2 in values2: #ex: (7,10)
                    if value2[0] >= value1[0] and value2[1] <= value1[1]:
                        sorteddic[key2].pop(sorteddic[key2].index(value2))
        onlybigs.setdefault(key1, sorteddic.pop(key1))
        break

#and a second clean in the end
readydic = clean(onlybigs)
```

This last step especially is taking too long because it compares each value for each key and my guess is the whole process can be done more efficiently somehow.

Any insights?

Comment: You have `3-2` in your `seq` list.  Is this a subtraction, or are you missing a comma?

Comment: corrected it and some other mistakes in the code

Comment: @ThiagoLuiz, the final `readydict` have lost indexes for the most items `{(1, 4, -5, 1, 4): [(7, 12), (10, 15)], (1, 4, -5, 1): [], (4, -5, 1, 4): [], (1, 4, -5): [], (4, -5, 1): [], (-5, 1, 4): [], (-2, 3): [(0, 2), (2, 4)], (1, 4): [(13, 15)], (4, -5): [], (-5, 1): [], (-2,): [], (3,): [(5, 6)], (1,): [], (4,): [], (-5,): []}` <-- empty lists. Is it not working as expected yet?

Comment: sorry, i just did ```cleandic = {}
for key, value in dic.items():
    if len(value) > 1:
        cleandic.setdefault(key,value)``` again at the end

Comment: @ThiagoLuiz, but you have `readydic`, not `dic` at the end. Please fix and update your code

Comment: Already did it, sorry for that

Comment: @ok, the final `readydic` above contains `{(1, 4, -5, 1, 4): [(7, 12), (10, 15)], (-2, 3): [(0, 2), (2, 4)]}`. Is that intended? i.e. should the result be "the farthest longest sequence" and "the earliest 2-number sequence" ? Can you clarify ?

Comment: Result should be any segment of the initial list that repeats at least once and it's not inside a bigger segment that also repeats. It's also sorted by the size of the segments (reversed).

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I have rolled back your last edit. Please don't change or add to the code in your question after you have received answers. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're doing things the hard way.

```
dic = {}
for p1 in range(len(seq)):
    for p2 in range(p1+1,len(seq)):
        dic.setdefault(tuple(seq[p1:p2]), []).append((p1,p2))
```

For each range, you are calling `.setdefault()`.  You should just use a default dictionary, which can automatically create a list for any unseen keys:

```
from collections import defaultdict

dic = defaultdict(list)

for p1 in range(len(seq)):
    for p2 in range(p1 + 1, len(seq)):
        dic[tuple(seq[p1:p2])].append((p1, p2))
```

---

Next, you're filtering the dictionary the hard way.

```
cleandic = {}
for key, value in dic.items():
    if len(value) > 1:
        cleandic.setdefault(key,value)
```

This can be expressed in one line, using list comprehension:

```
cleandic = { key: val for key, val in dic.items() if len(val) > 1 }
```

---

The next improvement comes from noting that the key portion of `(-2, 3): [(0, 2), (2, 4)]}` is completely recoverable from the value portion; using `(0, 2)` or `(2, 4)` as a slice of `seq` will return the appropriate sequence.  You do not need to maintain a dictionary; a list of lists is sufficient and less complex.  Instead of `cleandic`, you can have:

```
groups = [ val for val in dic.values() if len(val) > 1 ]
```

Instead of removing the second of these two dictionary values:

> #(1,4,-5,1,4,-5) : [(7,13),(10,16)]
>      #(1,4,-5) : [(7,10),(10,13)]

You now just need to remove the second of these two list entries:

> [(7,13),(10,16)]
>      [(7,10),(10,13)]

---

You can still sort this by noting that `(7,13)` represents a sequence of length 6.

```
groups = sorted(groups, key=lambda item: item[0][1] - item[0][0], reverse=True)
```

---

Any time you have to `.copy()` is good time to stop and think if there is another way to solve the problem.

```
    for key2, values2 in sorteddic.copy().items():
        ...
                  sorteddic[key2].pop(sorteddic[key2].index(value2))
```

Here, you are modifying `sorteddic` inside the loop, so you clearly can't loop on the `sorteddic` itself, which explains the need to copy the dictionary first.  Since the copy is itself in another loop, you are doing a lot of copies!

Moreover, this isn't even a loop!  It is just a way to extract the first item from the dictionary.

```
for key1, values1 in sorteddic.items():
    ...
    break
```

Rework the algorithm to not modify the container you're looping over:

```
def subset_of(long_groups, group):
    return any(lg[0] <= g[0] and g[1] <= lg[1] for long_group in long_groups
               for lg in long_group for g in group)

...

longest_groups = []
for group in groups:
    if not subset_of(longest_groups, group):
        longest_group.append(group)
```

Finally, you can rebuild your dictionary with the sequence tuples as keys:

```
readydic = { tuple(seq[group[0][0]:group[0][1]]): group for group in longest_groups }
```

Since all the dictionary copying has been removed, this should be significantly faster.

Comment: I don't think my example ```seq``` was great, because I have to keep smallers that happens outsite the biggers even if they same the same numbers. So here ```seq = [1,2,3,4,5,6,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,1,2,3,0]``` the ```(1,2,3)``` in the end has to be in readydic. I adapted your code to do this, is it ok if I answer my question with that? And one more question, turning values to list and back do dict doesn't become a time problem with biggers dicts?

Comment: From [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers), in particular the **Posting a self-answer** section, you are allowed to post a self answer, but it "_must meet the standards of a Code Review answer, just like any other answer. Describe what you changed, and why. Code-only answers that don't actually review the code are insufficient and are subject to deletion_".  Alternately, you could post a new follow-up question, cross-linking one to the other, showing what you've done and why, inviting addition code review feedback.

Comment: There is a performance impact with converting dictionary values to a list, and later turning the list back into a dictionary.  However, there is a much, much larger impact repeatedly copying the dictionary once for every entry in the dictionary.  A dictionary is a more complex data structure than a list; if you are merely iterating over all entries in the container, using a list instead of a dictionary will not be slower and might be slightly faster.  If you want to leave the container as a dictionary, that can work; the important aspect is removing the repeated copies.

Answer (score 3):

#### Optimized version

The crucial function can be thought through 3 phases:

*Aggregating **dictionary of sequential recurrences***

As was correctly mentioned **`defaultdict(list)`** is a more performant alternative to `dic.setdefault`.
Besides of that, as you've mentioned, input list could be of length `300`. In that case the initial approach will evaluate `len(seq)` 44850 times.
To optimize that we'll store the size of the input sequence in a separate variable **`seq_size = len(seq)`** and refer it in subsequent loops.

---

*Filtering out entries that weren't recurred (occurred once) with ordering*

Instead of defining `clean` inner function and generating a redundant dictionary `cleandic` - both filtering and sorting can be performed in one pass:

```
d = dict(sorted(((k, v) for k, v in d.items() if len(v) > 1),
                key=lambda x: len(x[0]), reverse=True))
```

---

*Filtering out entries that are part (included) of other longer sequences*

Instead of falling into a numerous noisy loops - a *string membership* trick can be applied. It's based on the idea of presenting string representations of *short* and *long* sequences as a *"needle"* and *"haystack"*.
It looks as:
`" 1 4 -5 "` **in** `" 1 4 -5 1 4 -5 "`.
Trailing spaces prevent incorrect matches like `"1 4 -5"` **in** `"1 4 -55 11 4 -5"` (which would be *truthy*)

---

The new implementation is placed into a function called **`find_recurrences`**.
(I've moved the old implementation into function `find_recurrences_old` for comparison)

```
from collections import defaultdict


def find_recurrences(seq):
    seq_size = len(seq)
    d = defaultdict(list)

    for i in range(0, seq_size):
        for j in range(i + 1, seq_size):
            d[tuple(seq[i:j])].append((i, j))

    d = dict(sorted(((k, v) for k, v in d.items() if len(v) > 1),
                    key=lambda x: len(x[0]), reverse=True))
    d_copy = d.copy()

    for k, v in d_copy.items():
        if k not in d:
            continue
        k_str = f" {' '.join(map(str, k))} "
        for k_ in d.keys() - set([k]):
            if f" {' '.join(map(str, k_))} " in k_str:
                del d[k_]

    return d
```

---

Ensuring that both functions return the same result:

```
In [79]: seq = [-2, 3, -2, 3, 5, 3, 7, 1, 4, -5, 1, 4, -5, 1, 4, -5]                                                         

In [80]: find_recurrences_old(seq)                                                                                           
Out[80]: {(1, 4, -5, 1, 4): [(7, 12), (10, 15)], (-2, 3): [(0, 2), (2, 4)]}

In [81]: find_recurrences(seq)                                                                                               
Out[81]: {(1, 4, -5, 1, 4): [(7, 12), (10, 15)], (-2, 3): [(0, 2), (2, 4)]}
```

---

But the **new** version has *time performance* advantage:

```
In [84]: %timeit find_recurrences_old(seq)                                                                                   
97.3 µs ± 212 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

In [85]: %timeit find_recurrences(seq)                                                                                       
80.5 µs ± 154 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Comment: checking your answer I found a +1 mistake in my code that got into yours. Edit was to short, in the first loop should be ```for j in range(i + 1, seq_size+1):``` Your code is a big improvement on mine but it gives a different result, the list i gave as exemple just doesn't show it. Try this: ```seq2 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,1,2,3]```
my code results:
```{(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6): [(0, 6), (7, 13)], (1, 2, 3): [(13, 16), (16, 19)]}```
your code results:
```{(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6): [(0, 6), (7, 13)]}```
The cause is the "needle" and "haystack" part.
Again, big improvement

Answer (score 0):

Use `collections.defaultdict()` rather than `dict.setdefault()`.

Instead of nested loops to find subsequence, keep a dict mapping items to their positions.  For each item in the sequence check if that item was in the sequence before.  If it is, only check for subsequences starting at those positions.  I think on average, this will do better than the nest loops:

```
seen_items = defaultdict(list)

for pos, item in enumerate(sequence):
    if item in seen_items:
        for other_pos in seen_items[item]:
            ...check for matching subsequences starting at pos and other_pos
            ...and add them to the dict of sequences...

    seen_items[item].append(pos)
```